# Algorithms to automatically determine optimal responsive image breakpoints

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-resizing

Cloudinary has published a tool that automatically generates breakpoints for responsive images: http://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/

The breakpoints and images are tuned using these knobs:

1. The resolution range (ex. 200 px to 1400px)
2. The minimum file size difference between each image
3. The maximum number of images to generate
4. Art direction by cropping the image to different aspect ratios

The problem of art direction can be easily solved by using smart crop tools and face detection. One example would be [smartcrop.js](https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js/).

The first 3 conditions are further complicated by:

1. Different image formats will have different file-size to image-size ratios.
2. Depending on the image itself, it will also have different file-size to image-size ratios.

The only way I can think of is to generate a few breakpoints, generate those images and then check the constraints and adjust and regenerate as needed. However, this brute-force approach seems to be extremely inefficient. Are there any algorithms for generating the responsive breakpoints (without the brute-forcing), given these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts about the points:

1. The resolution range (ex. 200 px to 1400px)
2. The minimum file size difference between each image
3. The maximum number of images to generate

It might not be correct all the time, but I would make the assumption that higher resolution always results in bigger file size. With other words the size of the file is a strong monotone growing function with the parameter image size.

This might not be true for all compression algorithms, but a quite good approximation for all of them.

With this assumption you can get any file size by a binary search in the image size space. This means You do not have to create that many different images to meed your needs.

**Remark:**
They seam not to use different image formats for the generated images. So the process is always done with only one file format.